# How to provide Hlit SingletonComponent to Dagger 2 dependencies in Hilt migration?

Tags: android, migration, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

One of our Dagger 2 components looks like this:

```
@Component(modules = [FragmentAModule::class], dependencies = [AppComponent::class])
@ViewScope
interface FragmentAComponent {
    fun inject(fragment: FragmentA)
}
```

And we inject it on a Fragment like this:

```
DaggerFragmentAComponent.builder()
    .appComponent(App.appComponent())
    .build()
    .inject(this)
```

Now I am trying to migrate Dagger 2 to Hilt, however, we can not migrate all at the same time, so I am trying to migrate only App-wise Singletons first, but I am not sure how to replace the `dependencies = [AppComponent::class])` part and also `appComponent(App.component())` part.

Is there any way to get Hilt SingletonComponent to use in Dagger 2 part?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: do you want to combine dagger2 and hilt?

Comment: @sasikumar Yes, because we can not migrate all of them together, so wish to migrate Singletons first. So wish to leave the code in the question, however I am not sure how to provide Hilt SingletonComponent to Dagger 2, or even if it is possible.

Comment: we have to use EntryPoint this case, refer this it may useful https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/linking-dagger-2-and-dagger-hilt-with-entrypoint-8992bd795a58#:~:text=Linking%20up%20Dagger%202%20to%20Dagger%20Hilt%20is%20Useful&text=take%20advantage%20of%20the%20additional,shown%20in%20the%20Google%20Codelab.